# How do you manipulate html text so that the text displayed on screen is different than the html

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, on screen text shows: "Black"
But when you inspect the html it shows:

```
<a class="class-name" href="some-link">8Fb15</a>
```

Or on screen is showing "White" but html shows:

```
<a class="class-name" href="some-link">XSigT</a>
```

Saw this somewhere and was curious how one might do it or decrypt it

Comment: The only way I can think of, off the top of my head, is to use CSS to hide the text (e.g. by setting `font-size: 0`) and then using `:before` or `:after` to insert some pseudo text into the page. Other methods (such as JavaScript) would edit the underlying DOM so the text would have changed to the new value when you inspect it.

Comment: Another way is to use a custom font that substitutes different glyphs for the actual letters.

Comment: If you're looking at the source code, it contains the static HTML loaded from the server at the page load. If you later change the content with JS, it is not reflected to the source code

Comment: @Brian that seems to be the case in an example I found as well. Never thought of that before but that's an interesting way to do it

Comment: @Paulie_D I mean, obviously I already searched SO otherwise I wouldn't be posting this question. So what exactly is the POINT of your comment? To point out that I didn't attempt it? Clearly I didn't ask someone to write the code for me. I'm simply asking for the right direction so I can attempt it myself, no?

Comment: How is it obvious that you searched? What attempts have you made and what results did you get? You haven't demonstrated anything other than positing two lines of code which mean nothing in isolation. You haven't referenced any similar questions/scenarios (and I'm certain they exist)..nothing. **You posted a problem and then dumped it on SO.**

Comment: @Paulie_D It's obvious I already searched through SO because otherwise I wouldn't have posted my question here. If you're so "certain" that a similar question exists, then find me one. Can't be that difficult am I right? But before that, I would suggest you [learn how to answer questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) or [learn to properly behave yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), either via Google or searching SO. I'm simply trying to learn so **if you don't have anything helpful to contribute, then Leave. Stack Overflow is not a place to whine.**

Comment: @tlqkfsusdk Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) You are expected to do and _show_ your research. Please don't complain if you are pointed to that fact, but take it as valuable input to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're most likely using what @Brian commented, a custom font that substitutes the glyphs for the actual letters.

If you're actually trying to make it harder for people to inspect element your webpage, then you could take a look at an [HTML Minifier](http://minifycode.com/html-minifier/) which makes it annoying as hell to look through with inspect element and impossible to read practically.

If you're just looking for how to make that somewhat encryption on your site then I would look into building your own custom font in which you can set different unicode identifiers for the letters.

Comment: HTML Minifier is not a good solution, since there are HTML Formatters (http://htmlformatter.com/).

Comment: It was a subpar solution as it doesn't really satisfy what he was asking. The more valid solution is that he creates his own custom font with the unicode identifiers which is then somewhat encrypted. There really is no true way to encrypt a webpage since a user must see the code that creates it.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up looking through the css and was able to located the eot file and work backwords from it